# How to give multiple properties to react component in shorter way?

Tags: reactjs

```js
<ReactComponent
      closeModal={this.infoModalToggle}
      customerFirstName={selectedObj.firstName}
      customerLastName={selectedObj.lastName} 
      indicatorNum={selectedObj.indicator}
      customerPhone={selectedObj.customerPhoneNumber}
      pickupTime={formatPickupTime}
      orderNum={selectedObj.orderNumber}
      numOfTotes={selectedObj.totes}
      numOfRefrigerated={selectedObj.refrigerated}
      numOfAmbient={selectedObj.ambient}
      numOfFrozen={selectedObj.frozen}
    />
```

In this code snippet there are multiple properties has given to the react component.Here my question is how to pass properties in better way rather than this .Is there possible way to pass all the properties using {...} or any other way.And how it will be destructing into the component.

Thanks

Comment: You could spread the `selectedObj` on the component and use the property names directly inside the component. `<ReactComponent closeModal={this.infoModalToggle} {...selectedObj}>`

Comment: const {customerFirstName,customerLastName} = this.props.selectedObj is this right ?

Comment: That's how you could do it if you wrote `<ReactComponent selectedObj={selectedObj}>`. You want to do `const {firstName, lastName} = this.props` with the spread.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use destructuring to pass down a lot of props but beware that they will be passed with the exact the same name as in the object you are destructuring.

You may, for instance, go for:

```
<ReactComponent
  closeModal={this.infoModalToggle}
  { ...selectedObj }
/>
```

But your props name will change from `customerFirstName` to `firstName` for instance.

If you think you can handle this, it's waaay shorter.

You may even pass down directly the object with:

```
<ReactComponent
  closeModal={this.infoModalToggle}
  selected={ selectedObj }
/>
```

It's quicker, but you still have prop names changed.